# SSDmobilenet pets config -> Faced error when tried to created tflite pb file from customize checkpoint created from transfer training

Tags: tensorflow

Faced error when tried to created tflite pb file from customize checkpoint created from transfer training

System information :

```
ubuntu - 18.0
tf.VERSION = 1.14.1-dev20190517
tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.12.1-2154-g3df6d99f3f
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = v1.12.1-2154-g3df6d99f3f
env : LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64
```

Tensorflow command:

```
python /object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py     
    --pipeline_config_path models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix model.ckpt-23595
    --output_directory /tflite/ 
    --add_postprocessing_op=true
```

Error log :

> TypeError: `export_tflite_graph()` takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the script. We will fix it shortly.
Thanks for flagging!

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Please fix ASAP